# Como pegar o tamanho total da tela mesmo que a janela do navegador esteja redimensionada?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu consigo obter o tamanho da janela do navegador através do seguinte código:

```
$(window).height();
```

Porém, esse método pega o tamanho atual.

Gostaria de saber se tenho como pegar o tamanho total da minha tela mesmo que eu redimensione.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Descobri que com esse código JavaScript consigo a altura e largura:

```
   var altura = screen.height;
   var largura = screen.width:
```